# Can we use char rnn to create embeddings for out of vocabulary words?

Tags: nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding, fasttext

I have word embeddings for 10 million words which were trained on a huge corpus. Now I want to produce word embeddings for out of vocabulary words.  Can I design some char RNN to use these word embeddings and generate embeddings for out of vocab words? Or is there any other I can get embeddings for OOV words?

FastText is capable of producing word embeddings for OOV but it does not have distributed way of training or GPU implementation, so in my case, it could take almost 3 months to finish training. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Question 1 (char-rnn for OOV words): yes, check [this article](http://aclweb.org/anthology/D17-1010.pdf) (contains a link to an implementation).

Comment: @mcoav Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.